# function call missing argument list

Tags: c++, odeint

I'm trying to use `odeint` (i.e. library for solving differential equations) inside a class but I couldn't. I really need to put it inside a class so that I can have control over my project. This is the error I'm getting `error C3867: 'robot::sys': function call missing argument list; use '&robot::sys' to create a pointer to member`

and this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

/* The type of container used to hold the state vector */
typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

class robot
{
    double g, dt, t;
    runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type> stepper;

public:
    state_type x;

    robot() : x(2)
    {
        x[0] = 1.0;
        x[1] = 0.0;
        t = 0;
        g = 0.15;
        dt = 0.1;
    }

    void move();
    void sys(const state_type &x, state_type &dx,  double t);
};


void robot::move()
{
    stepper.do_step(sys , x , t, dt );
    t += dt;
}


void robot::sys( const state_type &x , state_type &dx ,  double t )
{
    dx[0] =  x[1];
    dx[1] = -x[0] - g*x[1];
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   robot Robo;

   for ( size_t i(0); i < 100; ++i){
       Robo.move();
   }


    return 0;
}
```

When I try the solution that is suggested in the error message, I'm getting another error which is

`....\odeint\stepper\base\explicit_error_stepper_fsal_base.hpp(279): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments`

Comment: What is `g` in `robot::sys`? Did you mean `t`? It seems error is in the line `stepper.do_step(...)`. Try reading more about `do_step` and how is it used?

Comment: The first parameter to `do_step` should be a function object. Depending on your compiler's support for lambdas, you can use a lambda there, use `bind`, or write a separate functor class (since your function object has state with `g`).

Comment: @Hohit Jain, I mean `g`. It is a data member of robot class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys` is a non-static member function; they do not behave like normal functions because they have an implicit `this` parameter.

Possible fixes are:

(1) Use a C++11 lambda in place of `sys`:

```
void robot::move()
{
    stepper.do_step([this](const state_type &x, state_type &dx, double t){
        dx[0] =  x[1];
        dx[1] = -x[0] - g*x[1];
    }, x , t, dt );
    t += dt;
}
```

(2) Keep `sys` and use `std::bind` or `boost::bind`:

```
void robot::move()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    stepper.do_step(std::bind(&robot::sys, this, _1, _2, _3), x , t, dt );
    t += dt;
}
```

(3) Use a custom-written functor instead of `sys`:

```
struct System {
    double g;
    explicit System(double g) : g(g) {}
    void operator()( const state_type &x , state_type &dx ,  double t )
    {
        dx[0] =  x[1];
        dx[1] = -x[0] - g*x[1];
    }
};

void robot::move()
{
    stepper.do_step(System(g), x , t, dt );
    t += dt;
}
```

Note that in this case you can have your class store a `System` object instead of storing `g` and constructing it on each call to `move`.

Comment: thank you so much. I'm happy with the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your move function is passing sys as argument and the compiler suggests correct syntax for that. You can swap sys for appropriate lambda expression in the move function or use bind.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Comment: I've tried the suggestion but it throws another error.

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically - put your sys code into lambda expression and pass it as parameter into your do_step func.